# Swift - Select from Firebase by child value

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem. All I want is to select data from Firebase using Swift by child key's value

For example:

```
{
  posts:{
     post1:{
        userId:10
     },
     post2:{
        userId:11
     },
     post3:{
        userId:10
     },         
  }
}
```

So all I need is to fetch posts that contains userId:"10"
I've tried to use different options from StackOverflow questions - but still have no result((

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Firebase's queryOrderedByChild followed by queryEqualToValue as follows:

```
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts")
    let queryRef = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "userId").queryEqual(toValue: 10)
```

Then you can attempt to retrieve the values with your usual .childAdded, .value etc:

```
    queryRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in 

    })
```

Comment: I have a code 
`ref.child("posts").queryOrdered(byChild: "owner").queryEqual(toValue: uid)
        ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            let snap = snapshot.value as? NSArray
            for i in snap!{
                let val = i as? [String:AnyObject]
                print(val?["title"])
            }
        })`

Comment: and output:

`Optional(No church in a wild)
Optional(Bake chicken under tofu)
Optional(Create awesome robot)
Optional(Explode cow in a center of Stockholm)
nil
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

What am I doing wrong? It's fetching all the lines now. There is only two lines should be there :(

Comment: Will this approach, go and get all posts and then narrow them down to the post written by userId: 10? I need to know how this will affect my data downloaded from Firebase.